# Get the id value after an insert request

Tags: mysql, kohana, kohana-3

I need to get the value of an id when I insert a row in my database.

```
$query = DB::insert('scenarioeco', array('utilisateur_id', 'nom', 'prixAchatN', 'prixAchatP', 'prixAchatK', 'prixSemence', ))
        ->values($arrayData);

$query->execute();
```

As the id is auto incremented, I don't insert it directly with the request. But to make an other query, I need this value. Is there a way to do it with Kohana. (Something else of get the last row in the table) Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = DB::insert('scenarioeco', array('utilisateur_id', 'nom', 'prixAchatN', 'prixAchatP', 'prixAchatK', 'prixSemence', ))
        ->values($arrayData);

$result = $query->execute();
echo $result[0]; //Output is the last inserted id
```